# mongosql not starting on Red Hat 8: "error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Tags: mongodb, redhat, connector

I have isntalled mongodb on a Red Hat 8 and it's working fine.

Also, I installed mongo connector for BI through this tutorial: https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/master/tutorial/install-bi-connector-rhel/.

Now, trying to run mongosqld with the command:
`mongosqld`

I got this error message: `mongosqld: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

This is the openssl installed version: `OpenSSL 1.1.1 FIPS 11 sep 2018`

I already searched, but I couldn't find an answer that worked for this issue yet.

Does anyone knows how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try installing the OpenSSL 1.0 libraries on RHEL 8:

```
sudo dnf install compat-openssl10
```

These are meant for compatibility only. Since mongosqld doesn't support the newer OpenSSL version, it seems like you have no other option.